# XPath selecting attribute fails on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xpath, html

Here's a small test I ran with `expect.js`:

```
describe('xpath', function () {
    it('finds attribute nodes', function () {
        $(document.body).append('<string fooBar="bar"><data id="xyz"></data></string>');
        var xyz = document.getElementById('xyz');
        expect(xyz).not.to.be(null);

        var nodes = document.evaluate('../@fooBar', xyz, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
        var element = nodes.iterateNext();
        expect(element.nodeValue).to.equal('bar');
    });
});
```

I'm testing it on Chrome and Firefox with Testacular, and while it passes on Firefox, it fails on Chrome with an error saying that `element` is `null`. The really crazy part to me is that if I change `fooBar` to just `foo`, it passes on both systems. Chrome also breaks if I use `Foo` instead of `foo`. In other words, XPath querying on Chrome seems to break when the sought-for attribute has a capital letter in it. Is this normal behavior? Am I missing something? Or is this a bug in Chrome?

### UPDATE 1

I added in Google's Wicked Good XPath, and now Internet Explorer works, too, but Chrome still fails.

### UPDATE 2

The XPath query works on Chrome if the actual attribute has caps, but the XPath value is all lowercase.

Comment: Filed an issue here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=179453&thanks=179453&ts=1362167145

Answer (score 1):

Are you using XHTML? If so, the XHTML specification dictates that [all element and attribute names must be in lower case](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.2).

You may find that Chrome is only geared up for evaluating XPaths on that basis, whereas other browsers are more compliant with XML (where any case is valid).